# Cloud Formation : Docker Swarm Mode on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation

**Question : How do you bind and access a volume in your docker-compose once you are inside Manager Instance created by Cloud Formation?**

My Problem:

- My **docker-compose.yml** file is such that I need to bind an
  external Django Project Code with the services/containers which will
  be created by the stack but **Cloud Formation** functions on
  **EBS(Elastic Block Store) and EFS(Elastic File System)** and I don't know to use them to put my project in them and get them accessed by
  the stack.
- I have been practicing something on Docker Swarm since a week and now
  I want to deploy my docker-compose.yml on **AWS** using **"Docker for
  AWS" Cloud Formation Stack Template.**
- I saw this tutorial and followed too but in my project, I am mainly
  facing issues when I have to bind volume.
- In Cloud Formation for **Docker for AWS** when you ssh the manager
  instance the syntax is like:
  `ssh -i [your-pem-key] docker@[manager-instance-public-ip]`
- Now after getting into the manager what I did was I executed my docker-compose.yml in the same stack which was created early by Docker on AWS template by the syntax:

  `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml TestLab`

  but as because my app needs code how to bind it with a volume.
- I would like to say that `-v` mounts don't work here.

Links which I have already referred and discarded:

- https://github.com/thecodeteam/labs/tree/master/setup-dockerforaws
- https://blog.thecodeteam.com/2017/02/09/persistent-storage-docker-aws-not-a-mystery/
- https://dzone.com/articles/docker-swarm-mode-on-aws

etc..